# Binding: Property not found in Xamarin.forms using MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

**XFC0045 Binding: Property "Tittle" not found on "Page_Navigation.ViewModels.ThirdPageViewModel". Error getting from this area -  Page_Navigation\Views\ThirdPage.xaml**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Page_Navigation.ViewModels
{
    public class ThirdPageViewModel : BindableObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Matches> MatchesList { get; set; }
        
        public ThirdPageViewModel()
        {
            MatchesList = new ObservableCollection<Matches>();
            MatchesList.Add(new Matches { Tittle = "Tittle 1", Description = "Description 1" });
            MatchesList.Add(new Matches { Tittle = "Tittle 2", Description = "Description 2" });
            MatchesList.Add(new Matches { Tittle = "Tittle 3", Description = "Description 3" });
            MatchesList.Add(new Matches { Tittle = "Tittle 4", Description = "Description 4" });
        }
    }

    public class Matches
    {
        public string Tittle { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:Page_Navigation.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="VM:ThirdPageViewModel"
             x:Class="Page_Navigation.Views.ThirdPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="True"
             Title="Third Page">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <VM:ThirdPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MatchesList}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Tittle}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
                
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

> I don't know why this exception. I am using VS2019 and Xamarin.forms 4.8.0.1451

Comment: Try removing the `x:DataType...` from content page declaration and build again.

Comment: Thank you FabriBertani, Now it is working...

Comment: @FabriBertani please turn yo comment to an answer to be useful for others

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must remove the `x:DataType` property because it's related to Compiled Bindings and you already defined a BindingContext for the viewmodel.

Check about XF Compiled Bindings here: [Xamarin.Forms Compiled Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings)

Answer (score 4):

the best choice: add new additional x:DataType to DataTemplate tag

```
                <DataTemplate  x:DataType="VM:Matches" >
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Tittle}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
```

It is improving data binding performance